# Neo4j (3.5.14) BFS/DFS failure for interconnected nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a problem to tackle: find all reachable nodes path to which will be under certain weight.
Already solved problem from programming language perspective of view, but now I want to 
do it the right way through call to neo4j. 
Consider following node connections:

```
 1-(2)--3
 | \    |
(3)(9) (1) 
 |   \  |
 2-(9)--4-(1)-5
```

In case formatting is not clear:

```
1->2 distance:3
1->3 distance:2
1->4 distance:9
3->4 distance:1
2->4 distance:9
4->5 distance:1
```

Assumption is, for starting point 1 and overall weight=5  we could reach every single node:
1->2 (3)
1->3->4->5 (4)

I know it could also be done "manually" by searching for shortest paths to each node in db and finding all, to which weight is less than 5, however, I think bfs /dfs are more suitable for this since for large dataset manual solution would be really slow for any query. 
So I for bfs/dfs I found following solution:

```
Match(n:Place {name:"one"})
call algo.bfs.stream("Place", "Connection", "BOTH", id(n),
{maxCost:5, weightProperty:'distance'})
yield nodeIds
unwind nodeIds as nodeId
return algo.asNode(nodeId)
```

however, result is only nodes 1, 2 and 3 (directly accessible) and I can't quite get, why it is so. if I remove connections 1->4 and  2->4, result is as expected. Why is algo.bfs/dfs not working for such case? If I search with maxCost 11, result is as expected - all nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Neo4j, we had some from the analytics team take a look. We've confirmed this is a bug affecting both dfs and bfs implementations, we'll have a fix out with the next algos patch release.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there is an issue in the implementation of bfs procedure in the code. 
i have written a query which works as well here,

`Match p=(n:Place {name:'one'})-[r:connection*]-(place:Place) WHERE n<>place
WITH place,[n in nodes(p)|n.name] as list ,REDUCE (sm = 0, k in r|  sm+k.distance) as sm ORDER BY sm WHERE sm <=5 
RETURN  place.name as endNode, COLLECT(list)[0] as path,COLLECT(sm)[0] as weight`